# Help with understanding the look-at function (the view matrix)

Tags: 3d, transformations, mathematics, matrix, camera-matrix

I've been reading this [article](http://in2gpu.com/2015/05/17/view-matrix/) about the look-at function. I don't understand the part when they're trying to inverse the matrix N.
[image]
They say that R is orthogonal because all its row and column vectors are orthogonal unit vectors.
[image]
This means that for example

$[s_x, v_x, f_x, 0]^T * [s_x, v_x, f_x, 0]^T = 1$

or

$[s_x, v_x, f_x, 0]^T * [s_y, v_y, f_y, 0]^T = 0$,

but why?
Could anyone explain it to me or give a hint about why it's true?

**EDIT:**
I guess I have found the solution:
I can quite easily prove that $R^T*R=I$. So if I could prove that $R^T*R=I\Longrightarrow R*R^T=I$, then by definition R is orthogonal.

Is the following proof correct (I'm not really good at math)?
$
R^T*R=I \Longleftrightarrow
R*(R^T*R)=R*(I) \Longleftrightarrow
(R*R^T)*R=R \Longleftrightarrow
R*R^T=I
$

Comment: Because it is a rotation matrix. Look up the SO(3) group.